# How do Tumblr blogs become recommended?

Tags: tumblr

The Tumblr dashboard shows a few blogs that it "recommends" that I follow.

- Are these recommendations personalized?
- How are these recommendations generated? By followers/notes? Are they curated?

[image: recommended blogs]